# Two dimensional array and autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I would like to make a form with list of products.

When the user starts typing the product name, autocomplete should show the available options by name (first array element).

When the user chooses a product, the second form control should display a price (second array element).

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
Product name:
<textarea class="form-control" id="product_name" name="product_name" rows="1" cols="70" placeholder="" type="text" required></textarea>
<br>
Product price:
<textarea class="form-control" id="product_price" name="product_price" rows="1" cols="70" placeholder="" type="text" required>
</textarea>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    var tagi = [
        ["product_name_1", "10"],
        ["produc_name_2", "20"],
        ["produc_name_3", "20"],
    ];
    $( "#product_name, #product_price" ).autocomplete({
        source: tagi[0,1]
    });
});
```

...and js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dNLQa/159/

I am trying get this to work but I am stuck.

PS. The array will be generated by PHP, so if this needs to be in a different format I can do that easily.

Comment: There are no multidimensional arrays in Javascript. There are *nested* arrays, which is something different. The notation `tagi[0, 1]` does not make sense.

Comment: ok, thank you for clarification. Could you be so kind to help me and explain how can I call first element od arrays?

Comment: You can't, not like this at least. I suggest a different array layout - an array of objects (`[
        {name: "product_name_1", price: "10"},
        {name: "product_name_2", price: "20"},
        {name: "product_name_3", price: "30"}
    ]`). jQuery autocomplete supports displaying a certain property from the objects in an array.

Comment: @Tomalak ok, so the array like: http://jsfiddle.net/dNLQa/165/
And how can I call the elements to make a list?

Comment: By calling `Array#map` to extract the relevant property, just like Davide's answer shows. http://jsfiddle.net/dNLQa/166/.

Comment: @Tomalak I am trying hard to get this to work with objects property. I am receiving now all tree values for prices. Would you be so kind, to help me with this jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dNLQa/168/

Comment: Well, thinking about it... jQuery autocomplete likes it best when the object property it should display is called `label`. When such a property exists, there is no need to call `.map()`. I've renamed the object properties accordingly. The selected item is available as `ui.item` in the `select` callback. Compare. http://jsfiddle.net/dNLQa/169/.

Comment: thank you. BTW will be possible to use the same scenario for more than two properties, ex. buyer price, and seller price? IMHO should work, will try

Comment: Sure, add those properties to the objects. You can fill as many text fields as you like in the `select` callback. Keep in mind that the user might select nothing in the autocomplete, then `ui.item` will not be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your problem correctly. If so, you could search for the product if the user selected one from the autocomplete.

Forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vnxa2b09/4/

```
$(function () {
  function setPriceByProduct(prod, values) {
    for (var i = 0, len = values.length; i < len; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] == prod) {
        $('#product_price').val(values[i][1]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  var tagi = [
    ["product_name_1", "10"],
    ["produc_name_2", "20"],
    ["produc_name_3", "20"],
  ];

  $("#product_name, #product_price").autocomplete({
    source: tagi.map(function(val){return val[0]}),
    select: function (event, ui) {
      setPriceByProduct(ui.item.value, tagi);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: partially working, but in your jfiddle when I am trying to start typing product name I have only one option to choose from (one product) instead of three

Comment: @Tikky Updated the fiddle. You need to pass all values as a flat array to the source property. I archived it by mapping them to a new array.

Comment: @DavidePerozzi, in your fiddle, product_price can have product_name value.

Comment: @DavidePerozzi - awesome, thank you. 
Artgb - thank you, your solution works also

Answer (score 2):

You can separately call `autocomplete` and when select `product`, you can forcefully change `price` field.
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vnxa2b09/2/)

```
$( function() {
    function setPriceByProduct(prod, values) {
    for (var i = 0, len = values.length; i < len; i++) {
      console.log(values[i][0])
        if (values[i][0] == prod) {
        $('#product_price').val(values[i][1]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

    var tagi = {
      "product_name_1": "10",
      "product_name_2":"20",
      "product_name_3" : "20"
    };
  tagi1 = Object.keys(tagi);
  var tagi2 = Object.values(tagi);

    $( "#product_name" ).autocomplete({
      source: tagi1,
    select: function(event, ui){
       $('#product_price').val(tagi[ui.item.value]);
    }
    });
    $( "#product_price" ).autocomplete({
      source: tagi2
    });
});
```